# Entity Framework + Boolean Matrix

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

My goal is to hold a square (i.e. nxn) BOOLEAN matrix in a database which I can query and modify using the entity framework. I have created a class to model each row of the matrix called MatrixRow. The matrix holds boolean values, I want to be able to select a row, search through that row and find which columns are true and return a list/array/vector/(whatever would work best) containing the column numbers which hold the value true.

My matrix row class holds n boolean variables. When I query my table for an entire row I can't iterate through the variables because they are separate. I am still new to C#/ASP.net/Entity and can not figure out how to make an array a member variable of my class, or if it is even possible. The other way which I can't figure out is to somehow query each column of a selected row in the database. Either solution would work, I think.

Here is my MatrixRow entity Class

```
public class MatrixRow
{
    [Key]
    public int AttributeID { get; set; }
    //public bool?[] columns { get; set };      //Doesn't work
    public bool A1 { get; set; }
    public bool A2 { get; set; }
    public bool A3 { get; set; }
    public bool A4 { get; set; }
    public bool A5 { get; set; }
    public bool A6 { get; set; }
    public bool A7 { get; set; }
    public bool A8 { get; set; }
    public bool A9 { get; set; }
    public bool A10 { get; set; }
    public bool A11 { get; set; }
    public bool A12 { get; set; }
    public bool A13 { get; set; }
    public bool A14 { get; set; }
    public bool A15 { get; set; }
    public bool A16 { get; set; }
    public bool A17 { get; set; }
    public bool A18 { get; set; }
    public bool A19 { get; set; }
    public bool A20 { get; set; }
    public bool A21 { get; set; }
    public bool A22 { get; set; }
    public bool A23 { get; set; }
    public bool A24 { get; set; }
    public bool A25 { get; set; }
    public bool A26 { get; set; }
    public bool A27 { get; set; }
    public bool A28 { get; set; }
    public bool A29 { get; set; }
    public bool A30 { get; set; }
    public bool A31 { get; set; }
    public bool A32 { get; set; }
    public bool A33 { get; set; }
}
```

Here is where I've gotten so far on how to use it.

```
public void Build()
    {
        AttributeContext _db = new AttributeContext();
        using (VirusDescriptionActions usersShoppingCart = new VirusDescriptionActions())
        {
            String cartId = usersShoppingCart.GetVirusId();
            VirusDescriptionActions.VirusDescriptionUpdates[] cartUpdates = new VirusDescriptionActions.VirusDescriptionUpdates[DescriptionList.Rows.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < DescriptionList.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                IOrderedDictionary rowValues = new OrderedDictionary();
                rowValues = GetValues(DescriptionList.Rows[i]);
                cartUpdates[i].AttributeId = Convert.ToInt32(rowValues["AttributeID"]);

                var Row = _db.MatrixRow.Where(b => b.AttributeID == cartUpdates[i].AttributeId); 
            }
        }
    }
```

***EDIT***

So I have fixed the class definition to include the array

```
public class MatrixRow
{
    [Key]
    public int AttributeID { get; set; }
    public bool?[] columns { get; set; }
}
```

But now I try to use it in my database intializer file and I get an 'invalid initializer member declarator' error. I am guessing it is because I have to set the amount of memory first but I don't know how.

```
private static List<MatrixRow> GetMatrixRow()
    {
        var Rows = new List<MatrixRow> {
            new MatrixRow
            {
                AttributeID = 1,
                columns[0] = false,
                columns[1] = true,
            },
         };
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your

```
public bool?[] columns { get; set };
```

doesn't work is simple.

It needs to be changed to this.

```
 public bool?[] columns { get; set; }
```

The reason is the ; was misplaced.

Comment: @nhoughto It does happen. The errors will should you what is wrong you can then look at your code and see what is different. 
If this is all you needed please accept it. If not if you can update your question to be clearer that would help.

Comment: actually, encountered a small bump @deathismyfriend

I am trying to initialize this array in a list using just
    columns[0] = false;

It doesn't work I realize because I haven't actually declared the bool values, just the pointer to the array. Can I initialize the size in the class? Something like

public bool?[] columns { get; set; }  = new bool[10];   ???

Comment: @nhoughto then update your above post if it is about this or if it is about something else create a new question.

Comment: Yeah, will do. a littile too cumbersome for comments

Comment: Could you immagine how to build a table to model bool[] myField? I think EF has the same problem as you...

Comment: @bubi I have no idea what you are trying to ask ? Please specify clearly.

Comment: The first solution (A1..A33) was one of the right solutions and works with fixed Matrix. EF knows how many fields (and the name of the fields) to create. The bool[] cannot work.

Comment: @bubi the original question was about the error occurring at the bool[] since he declared it incorrectly. The new question in the edit should be a new question not an addition to the current one.

Answer (score 0):

EF can't model bool[] myField. You have 2 different ways:

1. Split main table in two tables (or POCO model in 2 classes), the related table should have 3 fields,main table id, arrayindex and boolean value. The main table should have the Id and probably the number of elements in the boolean array (but this is your choice).
2. You can use only 1 table with a string field to store a stream of YN or 01 and not map the array of boolean (set and get should work on the string field or, better, get and set on the string field works on the array). This method has some variants (i.e. serialize the boolean array in the string field).